# why 'arr.values()' throws an error "arr.values is not a function"

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

```
it('`values()` returns an iterator', function () {
    const arr = ['k', 'e', 'y'];
    const iterator = arr.values();
    iterator.next();
    iterator.next();
    terator.next();

    assert.deepEqual(iterator.next(), { value: void 0, done: true });
});
```

It didn't pass the test.
I tried it `arr.values()` on chrome console and got the same error.
Wasn't it a standardized Array methods?

Comment: There's a web compat issue with implementing the ES6 standard method. You can use `arr[Symbol.iterator]()` though to get the same

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Array#values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/values) is currently [not implemented in most browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/values#Browser_compatibility). In order for you to use it you need to transpile it via Babel.

Answer (score 2):

array.values is ECMAScript 2015 (ES6) - not currently implemented in most browsers.

From

[image]

From [Mozilla MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/values)